# ejs change value on click link

Tags: javascript, ejs

I have an app.js file where I have:

```
res.render("index", {
Login:true
})
```

and a file header.ejs where

```
    <%if (Login) {%>
        <ul class="nav justify-content-end">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link h3" href="#">Logout</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    <%} else {%>
        <ul class="nav justify-content-end">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link h3" href="#" >Login</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link h3" href="#" id="Register">Register</a>
              </li>
        </ul>
    <%}%>
```

How can I change the value of "Login" when one of the links is clicked?

example: click on logout, Login change to false and Navigation change

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you'd need to make a request back to the server, which can then change the value of `Login` for you.

Answer (score 0):

EJS only renders that file once. Either you have to redirect to the same page again (where `Login` will be toggled) such that EJS can rerender it, or you have to dome client side dynamic behaviour (using javascript)

Comment: Can you put an example?